# monaca, iOS11にて backgraound-image と position fixed を使用すると慣性スクロール中に表示位置がずれてしまう

Tags: monaca

monaca, iOS11, iPhone6sの環境です。

要素にbackgraound-image, position fixedを指定した場合、
慣性スクロール中に表示位置がずれます。
慣性スクロール位置を固定する方法はあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

backgraound-imageの使用をやめました。
imgタグを使い、transform3dの設定を行いGPU処理にすると対策できました。